# Problem in delete the file in windows vista, it says access denied

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I am facing problem in deleting file in windows xp?.. It always says that file cannot be deleted & another user using the file. But I haven't used that file & try to delete the file again after restarting from shutting down then also not working. Even I tried in command prompt where the file is listing but when I try to delete it displays "access denied". How can I delete that file?

Comment: Which file? Which version of Windows? You've cited Windows Vista and XP in your question, and tagged it with Firefox. Can you please provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

Check what the permissions are on the file. In Windows Vista and later you can right-click on the file, click `Properties`, and look under the `Security` tab to see if you have read/write access to the file. If you only have read access, your user does not have access to that file, and you will need to use an administrator account. You may need to take ownership of the file to delete it. You can do this by clicking the `Advanced` button, going to the ownership tag, and changing the owner to yourself. Then give yourself permissions to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this free tool:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlocker - About

http://unlocker.emptyloop.com/ - Official website

Comment: This is very dangerous to do: http://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows/15695#15695

Comment: Perhaps this is dangerous... But! I use this tool for several years and never had any problems. Still thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem where one is unable to delete corrupt files with windows xp. The solution was to start a command line and delete the file from there.

- -> Start -> Run command -> cmd
- start the taskmanager and kill the explorer process
- `del x:\PATH\FILENAME.END`
- Start the explorer from the taskmanager again. Select in the menu to start a task and write explorer

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open a cmd box. (Start > Run > cmd)
2. Open the Task Manager. (Right-click on the taskbar.)
3. Kill explorer.exe. Don’t close the Task Manager.
4. Navigate in the cmd box to the undeletable file.
5. Delete it with DEL (I used DEL *.* for an immensely gratifying
   delete experience).
6. Using the File menu in Task Manager, restart explorer.exe.

https://kmandla.wordpress.com/2007/03/31/howto-delete-undeletable-files-in-windows-xp/